Is the Fréchet derivative invertible in a neighborhood?
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a real Hilbert space and $F:\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$ be continuously Fréchet differentiable. Suppose that there exists a point $x\in \mathcal{H}$ such that the Fréchet derivative at $x$, $\mathsf{D}F(x):\mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}$, is invertible. Is it true that there exists a neighborhood $U\subseteq \mathcal{H}$ of $x$ such that $\mathsf{D}F(y)$ is invertible for each $y \in U$?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem
Look at Generalizations, Banach spaces

@AndreaAveni, that does not help.

@whpowell96 which I do

@BasicUser Why does it not help? $\mathsf{D}F(x)$ must be bounded by any reasonable definition of the Fréchet derivative. By the bounded inverse theorem the hypothesis of the inverse function theorem is satisfied, so you can use the local diffeomorphism $G$ of $F$ at $x$ to show that your desired property holds. If you don't have any specific objection to this argument, I am happy to type it up in more detail.

That section of Wikipedia completely answers your question. Why do you think it doesn't?

@DeanMiller, ok I see. Yes, I’d appreciate more details.

Suppose the function $F$ is continuously Fréchet differentiable on some non-empty open set $\Omega \subseteq \mathcal{H}$. In your case you have $\Omega = \mathcal{H}$. Furthermore, suppose that $x_{0}\in \Omega$ is given so that the Fréchet derivative $DF(x_{0})$ is an invertible linear operator. Since the Fréchet derivative at a point is always a bounded linear operator, the linear operator $DF(x_{0})$ is invertible. As $\mathcal{H}$ is complete, we can apply the bounded inverse theorem to conclude that $DF(x_{0})$ is a linear isomorphism of $\mathcal{H}$ onto $\mathcal{H}$. The hypothesis of the inverse function theorem for $F$ at the point $x_{0}$ is now satisfied. What follows is that there is an open neighbourhood $U\subseteq \Omega$ of $x_{0}$ and a continuously differentiable function $G\colon F(U) \to \mathcal{H}$ with the following properties.

The map $F$ is a continuously differentiable bijection of $U$ onto an open set $F(U)$.

The map $G$ is a continuously differentiable bijection of $F(U)$ onto $U$.


In particular, we have that the composition $G\circ F$ is defined on $U$ and is equal to the identity map on $U$. By the chain rule we have that $DG(F(x)) \circ DF(x)$ is equal to the identity operator on $\mathcal{H}$ for each $x\in U$. Similarly, the composition $F\circ G$ is defined on $F(U)$ and is equal to the identity map on $F(U)$. The chain rule again implies that $DF(x) \circ DG(F(x))$ is the identity operator on $\mathcal{H}$ for each $x\in U$. Therefore for each $x$ in the open neighbourhood $U$ of $x_{0}$, the linear operator $DF(x)$ is invertible with inverse $DG(F(x))$.

The given answer I feel is overkill. One does not need to apply the inverse function theorem at all; I’m pretty sure the proof of the inverse function theorem uses what I’m about to state below anyway (atleast the proof I know (e.g in Cartan or Abraham-Marsden) does).
For any Banach space $E$, the set (group actually) $\operatorname{GL}(E)$ of bounded linear isomorphisms of $E$ onto itself is open in $\operatorname{End}(E)$ (topology given by the operator norm). The proof of this fact is a simple consequence of the Neumann series (a fancy way of stating geometric series $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$).
Now since you’re assuming $F$ is continuously differentiable with $DF_{x}$ invertible (hence an isomorphism by Banach’s theorem) it follows that the preimage of $\operatorname{GL}(\mathcal{H})$ under $DF$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$.

Slightly more generally, for any two Banach spaces $E_1,E_2$, we have that the space $\operatorname{Isom}(E_1,E_2)$ of bounded linear isomorphisms $E_1\to E_2$ is open in $\operatorname{Hom}(E_1,E_2)$ relative to the operator norm. To prove this, note that if the spaces are not isomorphic, then the former is empty so it is trivially open; otherwise by fixing an isomorphism, we can ‘transport’ everything and so without loss of generality, we reduce to the case of $E_1=E_2$, which has already been addressed above via Neumann’s series.
Therefore, your statement holds more generally as well: if $E_1,E_2$ are Banach spaces and $\Omega\subset E_1$ is open and $f:\Omega\to E_2$ is continuously differentiable and is such that at some point $x_0\in \Omega$, the Frechet derivative $Df_{x_0}$ is an isomorphism, then there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ in $\Omega$ (namely $(Df)^{-1}\left(\operatorname{Isom}(E_1,E_2)\right)$) such that for each $y\in U$, we have that $Df_y$ is an isomorphism.

This is a nice argument. Thanks for sharing it!
